# Magento 2 - Filter through non anchor categories throws "The bucket doesn't exist." exception

Tags: magento2, category, error, frontend, layered-navigation

I am facing this issue on M2.3.5-p2 when filter through non anchored subcategory on the main category(anchored) page.

**Steps to reproduce**

- From the admin set parent category anchor to Yes.
- For one of it's subcategory set anchor to No.
- Now on the front end navigate to main category and on the layered navigation try to filter through sub category configured as non anchor.
- It will throw the exception "The bucket doesn't exist."

  ```
  Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): The bucket doesn't exist.
  ```

  [Check the screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/5585026/9d8f47cbc5695a4f99dd805e217c6fa3)

There are several post available related to it which only consists a workaround. Instead what is the root cause of the issue?Why magento won't allow to filter through non anchor categories.
Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul

Please have look [here](https://nileshdubey.com/magento2/bucket-does-not-exist/)

Might solve your issue

Happy coding

Comment: your solution won't work for me, even with reindex and cache flush.